# webpack extract text plugin prints a lot

Tags: webpack

I am using the [webpack extract text plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to extract styles into a css file. It prints a lot of stuff like this:

> Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
>           + 2 hidden modules
>
> Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
>           + 7 hidden modules
>
> Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
>           + 7 hidden modules
>
> Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
>           + 2 hidden modules
>
> Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
>           + 2 hidden modules
>
> Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
>           + 4 hidden modules

Is there any way to surpress it via config? It's pretty useless and cramps the terminal window.

Comment: `webpack --hide-modules` will remove `+ 4 hidden modules` line

Comment: It does but still id displays a bunch of "Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:" lines

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to suppress messages from child plugins by adding `{ stats: { children: false } }` option to your webpack config.

```js
module.exports = {
  stats: {
    children: false
  }
};
```

There is an [issue reported upstream](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/35) regarding chatty behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The answer using `stats` suppresses output from all children, including everything if the config is an array.

Call `webpack` with `--hide-modules` at the command line instead.